# Determining subspace of M_nn

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following are subspaces of M_nn: (an nxn matrix)

1. The set of all nxn matrices A such that tr(A) = 0
2. The set of all nxn matrices A such that tr(A) = 4

For the first part I let

A = [ a 0 ; 0 -a] and

B = [ b 0 ; 0 -b]

if we add A+B we get a matrix

[ c 0 ; 0 -c ]   (trace of A+B is still zero)

so it is closed under addition.
and similarly it is closed under scalar multiplication. Therefore part 1 is true.

How about for part 2? Im not sure how to approach this problem?

If A = [4 0 ; 0 0]

and B = [3 0 ; 0 1 ]

then A + B = [ 7 0 ; 0 1 ] which does not have a trace of 4. How could I prove this for ALL possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown it isn't a subspace, one counterexample suffices. But in general, the trace of two matrices is additive, i.e., $Tr(A+B) = Tr(A) + Tr(B)$, so for all $A$ and $B$ in your second set, $Tr(A+B) = 8$

Answer (score 1):

In general we have $\text{tr}(A+B)=\text{tr}(A)+\text{tr}(B)$.  The sum of two matrices with trace $4$ always have trace $8$.

In particular for part 2) you can just choose the $n\times n$ matrix with $4$ in the upper left corner and $0$ elsewhere and show that adding it to itself the trace is not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1. Do you know *(if no prove it!)* that
   $$\operatorname{tr}\colon \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$$
   is a linear form? hence $\ker(\operatorname{tr})$ is a subspace of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$: in fact it's an hyperplan i.e. a subspace with dimension $n^2-1=\dim \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)-1$.
2. Is the zero matrix in this set?